# Is it possible to have a close button with fixed position in jquery mobile popup/dialog?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a link that create a dialog with jquery mobile in my page :

```
<a href="url_to_popup" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup" data-rel="back">
    Info
</a>
```

I added the `data-rel="back"` attribute to have a close button in the header of the dialog but here's the problem, my text is quite long and I would like to keep the close button visible even when scrolling down the page. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: if your dialog is longer then the screen, perhaps a dialog isn't want you want at all.  I'd use a regular page with a fixed header instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible - that's the thing with Dialogs in general - you'll have to follow Patricia's suggestion and use a normal page with a fixed top header.